# Draw geom_line plot accurately for grouped, temporally continuous data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm struggling to plot some data accurately using `geom_line` from `ggplot2` and would be grateful for help. Also apologies for the large dataset posted; it wasn't possible to reproduce the mistake to be corrected in a smaller one.

I have data with `obs`ervations taken during certain `Utterance`s (only one shown here) at micro time steps for different `names` (i.e., speakers) and yielding different `value`s.

```
head(df2)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  Utterance   obs name  value
  <chr>     <int> <chr> <chr>
1 oh            1 A     2.418
2 oh            1 B     1.538
3 oh            1 C     0.111
4 oh            2 A     2.418
5 oh            2 B     1.538
6 oh            2 C     0.111
```

What I'd like to do is simply plot the `value`s grouped by `name`s and displayed in a separate panel for each `Utterance`. This is what I tried so far to get there:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = obs, y = value, color = name)) + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(~ Utterance)
```

But the resulting plot is partly incorrect, as the lines drawn for the `Utterance` value `oh` seem to be broken into different parts, with the lines **overlapping each other**, whereas they should be **temporally continuous**:

[image]

How can this issue be mended? And how can the different different `value` levels or steps be visually **connected**?

Reproducible data:

```
df3 <- structure(list(Utterance = c("oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", "oh", 
"oh", "oh", "oh", "oh"), obs = c(100L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 102L, 
102L, 102L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 104L, 104L, 104L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 
106L, 106L, 106L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 109L, 109L, 
109L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 113L, 
113L, 113L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 
117L, 117L, 117L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 120L, 120L, 
120L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 122L, 122L, 122L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 124L, 
124L, 124L, 125L, 125L, 125L, 126L, 126L, 126L, 127L, 127L, 127L, 
128L, 128L, 128L, 129L, 129L, 129L, 130L, 130L, 130L, 131L, 131L, 
131L, 132L, 132L, 132L, 133L, 133L, 133L, 134L, 134L, 134L, 135L, 
135L, 135L, 136L, 136L, 136L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 138L, 138L, 138L, 
139L, 139L, 139L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 141L, 141L, 141L, 142L, 142L, 
142L, 143L, 143L, 143L, 144L, 144L, 144L, 145L, 145L, 145L, 146L, 
146L, 146L, 147L, 147L, 147L, 148L, 148L, 148L, 149L, 149L, 149L, 
150L, 150L, 150L, 151L, 151L, 151L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 153L, 153L, 
153L, 154L, 154L, 154L, 155L, 155L, 155L, 156L, 156L, 156L, 157L, 
157L, 157L, 158L, 158L, 158L, 159L, 159L, 159L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 
161L, 161L, 161L, 162L, 162L, 162L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 164L, 164L, 
164L, 165L, 165L, 165L, 166L, 166L, 166L, 167L, 167L, 167L, 168L, 
168L, 168L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 171L, 171L, 171L, 
172L, 172L, 172L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 175L, 175L, 
175L, 176L, 176L, 176L, 177L, 177L, 177L, 178L, 178L, 178L, 179L, 
179L, 179L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 181L, 181L, 181L, 182L, 182L, 182L, 
183L, 183L, 183L, 184L, 184L, 184L, 185L, 185L, 185L, 186L, 186L, 
186L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 188L, 188L, 188L, 189L, 189L, 189L, 190L, 
190L, 190L, 191L, 191L, 191L, 192L, 192L, 192L, 193L, 193L, 193L, 
194L, 194L, 194L, 195L, 195L, 195L, 196L, 196L, 196L, 197L, 197L, 
197L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 199L, 199L, 199L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 201L, 
201L, 201L, 202L, 202L, 202L, 203L, 203L, 203L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 
205L, 205L, 205L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 
34L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 
39L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 43L, 
43L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 47L, 47L, 
47L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
52L, 52L, 52L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 56L, 
56L, 56L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 60L, 60L, 
60L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 63L, 63L, 63L, 64L, 64L, 64L, 
65L, 65L, 65L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 67L, 67L, 67L, 68L, 68L, 68L, 69L, 
69L, 69L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 73L, 73L, 
73L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 
78L, 78L, 78L, 79L, 79L, 79L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 82L, 
82L, 82L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 86L, 86L, 
86L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 89L, 89L, 89L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 
91L, 91L, 91L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 95L, 
95L, 95L, 96L, 96L, 96L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 99L, 99L, 
99L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 103L, 
103L, 103L, 104L, 104L, 104L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 
107L, 107L, 107L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 110L, 110L, 
110L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 113L, 113L, 113L, 114L, 
114L, 114L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 117L, 117L, 117L, 
118L, 118L, 118L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 121L, 121L, 
121L, 122L, 122L, 122L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 125L, 
125L, 125L, 126L, 126L, 126L, 127L, 127L, 127L, 128L, 128L, 128L, 
129L, 129L, 129L, 130L, 130L, 130L, 131L, 131L, 131L, 132L, 132L, 
132L, 133L, 133L, 133L, 134L, 134L, 134L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 136L, 
136L, 136L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 138L, 138L, 138L, 139L, 139L, 139L, 
140L, 140L, 140L, 141L, 141L, 141L, 142L, 142L, 142L, 143L, 143L, 
143L, 144L, 144L, 144L, 145L, 145L, 145L, 146L, 146L, 146L, 147L, 
147L, 147L, 148L, 148L, 148L, 149L, 149L, 149L, 150L, 150L, 150L, 
151L, 151L, 151L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 153L, 153L, 153L, 154L, 154L, 
154L, 155L, 155L, 155L, 156L, 156L, 156L, 157L, 157L, 157L, 158L, 
158L, 158L, 159L, 159L, 159L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 161L, 161L, 161L, 
162L, 162L, 162L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 164L, 164L, 164L, 165L, 165L, 
165L, 166L, 166L, 166L, 167L, 167L, 167L, 168L, 168L, 168L, 169L, 
169L, 169L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 171L, 171L, 171L, 172L, 172L, 172L, 
173L, 173L, 173L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 175L, 175L, 175L, 176L, 176L, 
176L, 177L, 177L, 177L, 178L, 178L, 178L, 179L, 179L, 179L, 180L, 
180L, 180L, 181L, 181L, 181L, 182L, 182L, 182L, 183L, 183L, 183L, 
184L, 184L, 184L, 185L, 185L, 185L, 186L, 186L, 186L, 187L, 187L, 
187L, 188L, 188L, 188L, 189L, 189L, 189L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 191L, 
191L, 191L, 192L, 192L, 192L, 193L, 193L, 193L, 194L, 194L, 194L
), name = c("C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"), value = c("0.111", "2.368", 
"1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", 
"0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", 
"2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", 
"1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", 
"0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", 
"2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", 
"1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", 
"0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", 
"2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", 
"1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", 
"0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", 
"2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", 
"1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", 
"0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", 
"2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", 
"1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", 
"0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", 
"2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", 
"1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", 
"0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", 
"2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", 
"1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", 
"0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", 
"2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", 
"1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", 
"0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", 
"2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", 
"1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", 
"0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", 
"2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.538", "0.111", "2.368", 
"1.538", "0.111", "2.368", "1.542", "0.111", "2.368", "1.542", 
"0.111", "2.368", "1.542", "0.111", "2.368", "1.542", "0.111", 
"2.368", "1.542", "0.111", "2.368", "1.542", "0.111", "2.368", 
"1.542", "0.111", "2.368", "1.542", "0.111", "2.368", "1.542", 
"0.111", "2.368", "1.542", "0.111", "2.368", "1.542", "0.111", 
"2.368", "1.542", "0.111", "2.368", "1.542", "0.111", "2.368", 
"1.542", "0.111", "2.368", "1.542", "0.111", "2.368", "1.542", 
"0.111", "2.368", "1.542", "0.111", "2.368", "1.542", "0.111", 
"2.368", "1.542", "0.111", "2.368", "1.542", "0.111", "2.368", 
"1.542", "0.111", "2.368", "1.542", "0.111", "2.368", "1.542", 
"0.111", "2.368", "1.542", "0.111", "2.368", "1.542", "0.111", 
"2.368", "1.542", "0.111", "2.368", "1.542", "0.111", "2.368", 
"1.542", "0.111", "2.368", "1.542", "0.111", "2.368", "1.542", 
"0.111", "2.368", "1.542", "0.111", "2.368", "1.542", "0.111", 
"2.368", "1.542", "0.111", "2.368", "1.542", "0.111", "2.368", 
"1.542", "0.111", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", 
"0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", 
"2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", 
"1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", 
"0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", 
"2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", 
"1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", 
"0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", 
"2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", 
"1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", 
"0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", 
"2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", 
"1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", 
"0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", 
"2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", 
"1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", 
"0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", 
"2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", 
"1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", 
"0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", 
"2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", 
"1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", 
"0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", 
"2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", 
"1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", 
"0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", 
"2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", 
"1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", 
"0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", 
"2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", 
"1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", 
"0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.348", "0.113", 
"2.496", "1.348", "0.113", "2.496", "1.351", "0.113", "2.496", 
"1.351", "0.113", "2.496", "1.351", "0.113", "2.496", "1.351", 
"0.113", "2.496", "1.351", "0.113", "2.496", "1.351", "0.113", 
"2.496", "1.351", "0.113", "2.496", "1.351", "0.113", "2.496", 
"1.351", "0.113", "2.496", "1.351", "0.113", "2.496", "1.351", 
"0.113", "2.496", "1.351", "0.113", "2.496", "1.351", "0.113", 
"2.496", "1.351", "0.113", "2.496", "1.351", "0.113", "2.496", 
"1.351", "0.113", "2.496", "1.351", "0.113", "2.496", "1.351", 
"0.113", "2.496", "1.351", "0.113", "2.496", "1.351", "0.113", 
"2.496", "1.351", "0.113", "2.496", "1.351", "0.113", "2.496", 
"1.351", "0.113", "2.496", "1.351", "0.113", "2.496", "1.351", 
"0.113", "2.496", "1.351", "0.113", "2.496", "1.351", "0.113", 
"2.496", "1.351", "0.113", "2.496", "1.351", "0.113", "2.496", 
"1.351", "0.113", "2.496", "1.351", "0.113", "2.496", "1.351", 
"0.113", "2.496", "1.351", "0.113", "2.496", "1.351", "0.113", 
"2.496", "1.351", "0.113", "2.496", "1.351", "0.113", "2.496", 
"1.351", "0.113", "2.496", "1.351", "0.113", "2.496", "1.351", 
"0.113", "2.496", "1.351", "0.113", "2.496", "1.351", "0.113", 
"2.496", "1.351", "0.113", "2.496", "1.351", "0.113", "2.496", 
"1.351", "0.113", "2.496", "1.351", "0.113", "2.496", "1.351", 
"0.114", "2.496", "1.351", "0.113", "2.496", "1.351", "0.114", 
"2.496", "1.351", "0.114", "2.496", "1.351", "0.114", "2.496", 
"1.351", "0.114", "2.439", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", 
"0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", 
"2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", 
"0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", 
"2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", 
"0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", 
"2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", 
"0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", 
"2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", 
"0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", 
"2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", 
"0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", 
"2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", 
"0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", 
"2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", 
"0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", 
"2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", 
"0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", 
"2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", 
"0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", 
"2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", 
"0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", 
"2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", 
"0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", 
"2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", 
"0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", 
"2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114", "2.41", "1.351", 
"0.114", "2.41", "1.351", "0.114")), row.names = c(NA, -901L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I am not sure this is what you want but have you tried adding `group = name` in the `aes()`? This will link the lines (temporally) belonging to the same name (with the same color). But it will make them go up and down which might not be what you want.

Comment: That connects the lines, which is good, but it produces some artificial oscillation

Answer (score 0):

For trend plots it's often useful to group the data by the x-axis first.  Is this helpful?

```
df3 %>% group_by(obs,name, Utterance) %>% 
  summarise(value=mean(as.numeric(value),rm.na=T)) 
%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=obs,y=value,color=name,group=name))+geom_line()+
  facet_wrap(~Utterance)
```

Comment: Yes, that gives the correct result. Please help me understand what this does: `summarise(value = mean(as.numeric(value), rm.na=T), Utterance=first(Utterance))`- how does the `mean` come into play here?

Comment: the `summarise` command computes new values based on the `group_by` command. So, for the group formed by obs+name, we compute the mean of value.  See https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/ for more info.  If this is helpful, please mark the answer correct.  Thanks!

Comment: I've found that once you have more than one `Utterance` value you also need to `group_by` `Utterance`- maybe include this in the post?

Comment: Most likely.   If you edit your question to include multiple Utterance values, then I can redo the answer/code as needed.

Comment: I can't because of space limits imposed by SO

Comment: One more Q: taking the grouped means surely changes the actual values in `value`, correct? If it does, then are the values plotted still correct?

Comment: The values are computed correctly. Whether or not the mean value is useful for your purposes is a separate matter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239368/discussion-between-ben-and-chris-ruehlemann).

Comment: Sure the mean values are computed correctly, but why should I want to plot them when I have actual values?

Comment: So the question you will need to answer before I accept the solution you propose is this: are the values plotted still the actual values?